Show enabled shipping methods on product page
I'm using Woocommerce and I need to show shipping methods on the product page but I cannot make it so it only shows enabled shipping methods instead of all shipping methods loaded.
Here is the code:
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'shipping_rates_single_product' );
function shipping_rates_single_product() {
    global $product;
   if ( ! $product->needs_shipping() ) return;
   $zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();
   echo '<div><span class="qodef-woo-meta-label"> ' . __( 'Envíos', 'woocommerce' );
   echo '</span><ul>';
   foreach ( $zones as $zone_id => $zone ) {
      $zone_shipping_methods = $zone['shipping_methods'];
      foreach ( $zone_shipping_methods as $index => $method ) {
             $instance = $method->instance_settings;
             $cost = $instance['cost'] ? $instance['cost'] : $instance['min_amount'];
             echo '<li><span class="qodef-woo-meta-value">' . $instance['title'] . '<br>';
             echo $instance['description'] . '</span></li>';
      }
   }
   echo '</ul></div>';
}

Any idea what I can change to show only enabled shipping methods?

Does the solution provided below work for your question?

According to code, provided in question post, to get only enabled shipping methods instead of all shipping methods in woocommerce plugin,
the following code condition should be put in code.
if($method->enabled === 'yes')

So, the following code can be used.
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'shipping_rates_single_product' );
function shipping_rates_single_product() {
    global $product;
    if ( ! $product->needs_shipping() ) return;
    $zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();
    echo '<div><span class="qodef-woo-meta-label"> ' . __( 'Envíos', 'woocommerce' );
    echo '</span><ul>';
    foreach ( $zones as $zone_id => $zone ) {
        $zone_shipping_methods = $zone['shipping_methods'];
        foreach ( $zone_shipping_methods as $index => $method ) {
            if($method->enabled === 'yes') {
            /* Here, the code to get shipping method details should be there. */ 
            }
        }
    }
    echo '</ul></div>';
}

